# How do I evade the stream of bullets from a Kerberonyx

Tags: returnal

I'm having a bit of a hard time with one particular enemy type, I'm pretty sure it's the Kerberonyx. Big, orange and spews a long stream of red bullets.

I find evading their attacks to be particularly difficult. Dashing through it doesn't seem to work reliably, the stream of bullets lasts long enough that it'll usually hit me after dashing while the dash is still on cooldown. Just sprinting sideways also isn't fast enough when they sweep with their attack. The only thing that works somewhat for me is hiding behind pillars, but that isn't always possible.

Any tips on how to deal with this enemy type?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to dodge these except hiding behind something. But simply rushing them and using melee attacks does work well against them. The melee attack stuns them for a bit, so this is reasonably safe unless there are too many other attackers close. This of course requires that you have unlocked the melee attack.